# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function (C++ on Atom Editor)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, atom-editor

fs.js:157

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

at maybeCallback (fs.js:157:9)
at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1290:14)
at ChildProcess.child.on (/root/.atom/packages/gpp/index.js:57:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596:12)
```

I recently ran apt-get update on my Kali Linux machine and now whenever I use the c++ compilation package (gpp by livace) it throws this error (not in the way normal compilation errors are displayed). I know its not the code as the same error crops up in all projects, even ones that are confirmed to work.

**INFORMATION:**
cat /etc/issue: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l
gcc --version: gcc (Debian 8.3.0-19) 8.3.0
apt-get upgraded yesterday, aug 9 2019

I think it may be a problem with atom or some configuration thing.

Please help your fellow programmer!

Answer (score 0):

Used a different compile and run package (gcc-make-run) and everything worked ok. Most likely an issue that the gpp by livace package's (it's made in javascript) had with the update.